# ¿Cómo conectar AMP con mysql?

Tags: amp

AMP es un proyecto de Google que optimiza los sitios web para móviles para obtener una rapidéz de carga espectacular. Pero todas las páginas tienen que estar en HTML. ¿De qué modo puedo conectar la página con Mysql base de datos sin que deje de cumplir las reglas de AMP?

> https://www.ampproject.org/

Escribir `<?php echo 'Lo que sea'; ?>` me muestra el código tal cual escrito, desconozco la forma de incluir php en páginas de html y me temo de que sea imposible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que todavía no has entendido del todo la relación entre el lado cliente y lado servidor en el modelo web.

Lo que le llega al navegador (browser) cuando debe mostrar una página web *siempre* es HTML (además de otros recursos: imágenes, estilos css, javascript, etc). Ese es el "lado cliente" (lo que ocurre en el navegador de tu PC o movil).

PHP (y otros lenguajes que funcionan del "lado servidor") simplemente generan código HTML, que es enviado al cliente. EL cliente no sabe ni le importa en qué lenguaje fue generado el HTML que recibe.

AMP tiene que ver con el lado cliente, con el HTML que le llega al cliente.  Por lo tanto, no tiene ninguna importancia el lenguaje que hayas usado en el lado servidor para generar ese HTML.

Comment: Gracias por tú repuesta!

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado mi respuesta: todas las páginas no tienen porqué estar en HTML, pueden ser `.php` y siguen siendo válidas para AMP.

Se puede comprobar escribiendo

```
localhost/loQueSea/index.php#development=1
```

El resultado (al `inspeccionar elemento` en Chrome):

> AMP validation successful.